# How to parse a lot of txt files with pandas and somehow understand from which file each raw of the table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing the name, gender, and quantity of people with their names. There are a lot of text files (>100). Each of them has the same information with different quantity parameters but for 1880, 1881 .... 2008 years. 
Here is a link to make it more clear: https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/tree/2nd-edition/datasets/babynames
How can I import all of these files and mark raws with appropriate years? 
So the table looks like this:

```
YEAR   NAME  GENDER  QUANTITY
1998   Marie    F      2994  
1996   John     M      2984
1897   Molly    F       54
```

The main concern is how to mark each raw with appropriate year according to the filename.

Here is my code for 1 file, but i need to do the same for more than 100 text files...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("yob1880.txt", header=None)
df["year"] = 1880 # add new column according to the file`s year
print(df)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow :) Can you write your starting code in the post?

Comment: The Files you are referring there is no years defined rathe files are with created with years.

Comment: In case you are able to import all files , Do you need `df["year"] = 1880` for all?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, I have files named yob1881.txt, yob1882.txt but I don`t have such column in the datasets, is it possible to add such column according to the name of the file?

Comment: if this data from yob1881.txt file, it`s "Year" column should have value 1881, if this data from yob1994.txt file - it should have 1994 value in the "Year" column and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. How to extract year from filename and assign to new column.
2. How to concatenate multiple dataframes.

You can use string slicing and [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for the former; [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) for the latter. Assuming your filenames are of the format `yobXXXX.txt`:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(fn).assign(YEAR=int(fn[3:7])) for fn in filenames)
```

Or if you wish to ignore indices:

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(fn).assign(YEAR=int(fn[3:7)) for fn in filenames),
               ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: the trick with assign works well, but concatenation works wrong in this case
It gives a huge matrix with tons of columns and NaN values...

Comment: Update: it worked after I add the names for the columns by adding:
new_df.columns = ["Name", "Gender", "Quantity"]
Thanks a lot!